# Save a Sqlite database to a file

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have a Sqlite database which I retrieve the data inside and insert them in a `List <T>`. I would like to be able to save this list in a file inside the device, or directly the SqLite database in order to be able to recover it even when the application is restarted.

Using the `File.Write()` method it does not seem to work as from what I understand it can write strings or bytes. Any suggestions?

```
string LocalDB = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "LocalDb.sqlite");

var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(LocalDB);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<HumorDiary>();

var query = conn.Table<HumorDiary>();
var PagineDiario = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: An SQLite database is already a file.

Comment: so you don't even need to manually save it? if I try to execute the code I entered, an exception comes out telling me that the dabatase does not exist

Comment: `SQLiteAsyncConnection` will create the db file if it does not exist

Answer (score -1):

```
string LocalDB = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "LocalDb.sqlite");

var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(LocalDB);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<HumorDiary>();

var query = conn.Table<HumorDiary>();
var PagineDiario = await query.ToListAsync();
```